# How do I start a Cassandra cluster on macOS?

Tags: cassandra, macos-ventura

I am trying to start a Cassandra cluster on my local machine (macOS Ventura 13.5.1), the details of the cluster are as follows:

- Cassandra Version: 3.7
- Number of Nodes: 5

I've manually created the network interface aliases:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.3
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.4
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.5
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.6
```

`ccm create easybuy -v 3.7 -n 5 -s --pwd-auth` raises an OS Error: Error No. 48 as the address is already in use. During the handling of the exception, another exception occurs: "Unavailable Socket Error: Inet address 127.0.0.1:7000 is not available."

`sudo lsof -i :7000` reveals that three processes are running on the port:

1. Control Center (2): using both IPv4 and IPv6 to listen on port 7000
2. Java: using IPv4 to listen on port 7000

Nodes in the cluster are unable to exchange data and information as a result. I am just learning about the Cassandra distributed database, I've thought about using another port for inter-node communication.